# Eclipse - How to retrieve the tfs changeset number so it can be displayed within Java class

Tags: java, tfs, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, changeset

I am trying to retrieve the changeset number of a file, so I can place within a comment block at the top of the file.

I have already retrieved other details such as comments, author and date and time by the code below.

**Code**

```
String comments = pc.getPendingChanges().getComment();
String author =  pc.getPendingChanges().getAllPendingChanges()[0].getPendingSetOwnerDisplay();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                Date date = new Date();
```

**PC is:**

```
final PendingCheckin pc =  getPendingCheckin();
```

**Edit**

Any tips on how to improve the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String version =  String.valueOf(pc.getPendingChanges().getAllPendingChanges()[0].getVersion());